# Is it possible to hard code the AREF instead of using a pin?

Tags: atmega, adc

Is it possible to hard code the reference value instead of using the pin 21 (AREF) on the ATMEGA168?

Comment: Quoting from the [ATmega168A datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf) section 24.5.2: _If no external voltage is applied to the AREF pin, the user may switch between AV CC and 1.1V as reference selection._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the majority of ADC principles rely on comparision of voltage, current or charge you always need a physical reference that cannot be bypassed by hardcoding. In this case a reference voltage is needed. On the `ATmega 168` you can either use the external reference pin `AREF`, or the controllers power supply voltage `AVcc`, or a built-in 1.1 V voltage reference diode 'Vref`.

You can set the reference source by programming `ADMUX` (ADC multiplexer selection register) as stated in the [ATmega48/88/168 data sheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2545.pdf) page 261:

```
//using avrgcc:
//select internal 1.1 V ADC reference
ADMUX |= 0b11000000;
```